# saving data into custom cdr field

Tags: asterisk, pbx, cdr, trixbox

I created custom field "rec_name" id table "cdr", database "asteriskcdrdb". In this field I want to store recording name. I know I should do it by adding this line in one of .conf files, but where?

`exten => s,1,set(CDR(rec_name)=${CALLFILENAME})`

I can do it by sql statement, too, but I don't know where is the file that saves details of call into database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For mysql you need add into /etc/asterisk/cdr_mysql.conf

```
[aliases]
rec_name=rec_name
```

If you  HAVE aliases section, just add to it

```
rec_name=rec_name
```

Comment: In current versions (1.8+) there are no need do such aliases. Just need add field to DB table and restart asterisk or do cdr_mysql.so unload/load.

Comment: `module reload cdr_mysql.so` for Asterisk 1.8.20.1, I needed to add the alias in cdr_mysql.conf